# Ownership to subcontainers and objects in registry using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, registry, windows-7-x64

I am not sure this is possible in PowerShell.

What I am trying to do is to apply "Replace owner on subcontainers and objects" in registry using PowerShell script.

For example, in HKLM\Software\Policies\XXXX folder I want to take ownership of the folder and also apply to subcontainers and objects.

Can someone show me how to do it in Powershell script?

[image: Ownership in registry folder]

Comment: I don't think there's a way to automagically do that via PowerShell, you'll probably need to get a recursive list of the child objects and apply the ownership to each in a loop.